# How can I modify ANTLR4 grammar such that left association of operator can be supported?

Tags: antlr4

I want to support the following input as it is with a provided grammar.

This does not work

```
with [{id: 1},{id: 2}] as a
return a[0].id, a[1].id
```

It works if we change it to be:

```
with [{id: 1},{id: 2}] as a
return (a[0]).id, (a[1]).id
```

The relevant part of the grammar is here:

```
oC_PropertyOrLabelsExpression
                          :  oC_Atom ( SP? oC_PropertyLookup )* ( SP? oC_NodeLabels )? ;
```

This is the full grammar:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/artifacts.opencypher.org/M18/Cypher.g4

Is there anything we can do by modifying the grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
oC_StringListNullOperatorExpression
 :  oC_PropertyOrLabelsExpression ( oC_StringOperatorExpression
                                  | oC_ListOperatorExpression
                                  | oC_NullOperatorExpression
                                  )*
 ;
```

into:

```
oC_StringListNullOperatorExpression
 :  oC_PropertyOrLabelsExpression ( oC_StringOperatorExpression
                                  | oC_ListOperatorExpression
                                  | oC_NullOperatorExpression
                                  | oC_PropertyLookup
                                  )*
 ;
```